# How or when is a pull request created?

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

okay , so here's the scenario, I have a repository named "New_Test_repo" that will be accessed by developers on my network. I have two branches on my repo : master and develop. I have two users created one for the admin and the other is a TestUser. This TestUser has write permissions to the develop branch. So now here's my question, when the testuser has finished his development and pushes to the develop branch on my "New_Test_repo", shouldn't a pull request be created?

Note that I have configured the pull requests setting on my repo to have atleast 1 approver to go through. Am I getting this right ? Because when I replicated this scenario, i see that no pull request was created but the TestUser's commit was pushed successfully to the central repo "New_Test_repo" after authentication.

So this is my question : Why wasn't a pull request created in this scenario? Can someone enlighten me on this ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about vendor-specific issue

Comment: Hi How do you want me to modify this question or the tags?

Comment: @number5 I disagree. Many questions on SO are platform- and vendor-specific.

Answer (score 0):

First some explanation on pull requests...

When you file a pull request, all you’re doing is requesting that another developer pulls a branch from your repository into their repository.  In this case, it sounds like TestUser has access to the develop branch.  This is why the user is allowed to commit their changes.  If you now want a pull request created, follow these steps in Stash.  Independent of failed merges, I am unsure how to get Stash to automatically create pull requests.

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/STASH/Using+pull+requests+in+Stash#UsingpullrequestsinStash-Creatingapullrequest

Answer (score 0):

Does testuser created a new branch instead of commiting in the `develop` branch? As to my understanding, testuser need to create a different branch from `develop` and already forked your repo. Here's the workflow that I'm familiar with:

eg. testuser clone and create a new branch from `develop`

```
git clone http://user/some-repo.git
git checkout -b "feature/testuser"
git commit -am "lots of bug fixing."
```

then testuser need to push the branch to his/her own repo, not yours.

```
git push origin feature/testuser
```

Afer that, testuser need to create a pull request through his/her own repo 
which then will be reviewed by you.

Here's some link for your references:

- [making pull request - Bitbucket](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/making-a-pull-request/example)
- [making pull request - Github](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/)

Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Why wasn't a pull request created in this scenario?

Because TestUser has direct write permissions on the `develop` branch. If you want to require users to make a pull request for changes, you need to not allow them write permissions. Instead of pushing directly to the branch, TestUser can make a pull request. A pull request is basically saying "Hey, I have some changes for you to look at and decide whether or not to accept them." On the other hand, pushing commits directly to the central repo is saying "Here are my changes whether you like them or not."